Не получается прочитать txt файл. python
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  filepath = f'{path}' + 'Blacklist.txt'
  if os.path.exists(filepath) == False:
        with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
              file.write('')
              print('Файл создан')
  with open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        if message.from_user.id in file.readlines():
              print('он тут')
        else:
              print('его тут нет')
        print(file.readlines())
        print(message.from_user.id)

содержимое файла Blacklist.txt:
228
выводит в консоль:
его тут нет
[]
228
Как мне это поправить?

это не совсем так, файл открывается на запись только в том случае, если существует, если нет то часть кода пропускается

Не нужно два раза делать readlines - после первого вызова readlines позиция в файле будет на конце файла. Второй вызов этого метода всегда вернет пустую строку. Нужно или перематывать на начало перед вторым readlines, либо один раз сохранять в переменную, потом уже проверять и печатать.

но почему же он тогда не выводит 'он тут'?

Я думаю у вас просто новый пустой файл в каком-то другом месте создался, не там где вы готовый файл положили. И из этого же пустого файла читается.

к сожалению нет, я проверял, а если оставить один readlines, то он выводит 228 и 'его тут нет'

А, ну значит message.from_user.id - целое число, а из файла строки читаются.

Блин вы правы, я второй раз на те же грабли наступаю, спасибо большое

Попробуйте вставить полный путь файла данного файла .

Помог комментарий insolor

А, ну значит message.from_user.id - целое число, а из файла строки читаются.

